# App crashes only on the iPod Touch 4th generation

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, crash, ipod-touch

I have an app that crashes often on the iTouch 4th gen. It is fine on all other devices, including iPhones and iPads. When I run it with Xcode on this device, it does crash, but with no error messages. I have also profiled with Leaks and saw no leaks, but again it crashes  with no error messages. I do receive memory warnings. Live Bytes never goes higher than around 5MB so I don't quite understand the memory warnings.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone has experience with this device and may have some ideas on the cause of the issue.

Under required device capabilities, I have only this: Item 0 - armv7

Running iOS6

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the memory capacity of iTouch 4th gen is smaller than that of the other devices. Or there might be other apps open that make memory for your running app smaller too.